# Online Java Compiler and runner

Tags: java, cloud

I am designing an architecture for a simple cloud based app that compiles and runs java programs.

I am planning to expose services via SOAP through which a client can provide source to the server.
The server would respond with Log messages like compilation failures etc or success messages. Basically the console output.

**Questions**

1. From an architecture point of view what are the security considerations that I should be aware of and what would be the right way to do it?
2. What other validations should I put in before code compilations and what other things do you see that need to be taken care while implementing this in the cloud?
3. Are there any open source APIs that might already take care of above things?

---

I have come across **javax.tools.JavaCompiler** and other utilities that should do the job.

Comment: What are you asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code compilation isn't too dangerous because the only program that is running is the compiler. What you should worry about is the actual running of their compiled Java program.

If you haven't already, look into [SecurityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). Basically, you'll want to make your own class extending SecurityManager and then override all those methods. If the program shouldn't be able to do something, you throw a `SecurityException`. That's pretty much the easiest way to sandbox something in Java. Once you do that, you simply call `System.setSecurityManager(mySecurityManager);`